# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 weblogic 12c deployment error

Tags: java, weblogic12c

When I am deploying an java application at Weblogic 12c, I getting an error.
Log seems like this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.<init>(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.AnnotationMappingsImpl.loadAnnotatedClasses(AnnotationMappingsImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ApplicationContextImpl.processAnnotationMappings(ApplicationContextImpl.java:1001)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ApplicationContextImpl.getAnnotatedClasses(ApplicationContextImpl.java:1026)
    at weblogic.j2ee.managedbean.ManagedBeanModuleExtensionFactory.create(ManagedBeanModuleExtensionFactory.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.createModuleExtensions(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:264)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.initDrivenObjectArray(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:107)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I could not find what is the main problem and how can be fixed. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you didn't find your main problem and you didn't post your code, what do you expect strangers on the Internet will do for you?